# Drawing n-pointed star opengl c++

Tags: c++, opengl

So I am trying to draw a n-pointed star using opengl and I'm running across a problem when drawing stars that have multiple of 3 points.

The output for any other looks something like this eleven point star:

[image: img]

The output for something like a nine point star is nine point star:

[image: img]

The code I'm using to generate vertices is below. could really use the help.

```
srand(time(nullptr));
numVertices = 6 * (rand() % 15 + 5);

int numPoints = numVertices / 3;
float r = 0.95;
drawMode = GL_FILL;
vPos = 0;
vColor = 1;
const float M_PI = 3.1415926535897;
float DegToRad;
cout<<numPoints<<endl;
//if(((numPoints/2)%3) !=0)
DegToRad = 2*M_PI / numPoints;
//  else
//    DegToRad = 2*M_PI / (numPoints);

glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
cout<<"Graphics initialized"<<"\n";
VertexData* vertices = (VertexData*)malloc((numVertices+1) * sizeof(VertexData));

for(int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++)
{
    float DegInRad = i * DegToRad;

    if(i % 3 !=0 )
    {
        if(i % 2 == 0)
        {
            cout<<"Drawing triangle point "<<i<<" at "<<r*cos(DegInRad+(M_PI/2))<<","<<r*sin(DegInRad+(M_PI/2))<<endl;
            vertices[i] = {{1.00,0.00,0.00}, {r*cos(DegInRad+(M_PI/2)), r*sin(DegInRad+(M_PI/2))}};
        }else {
            cout<<"Drawing triangle point "<<i<<" at "<<r/3*cos(DegInRad+(M_PI/2))<<","<<r/3*sin(DegInRad+(M_PI/2))<<endl;
            vertices[i] = {{1.00,1.00,1.00}, {r/3*cos(DegInRad+(M_PI/2)), r/3*sin(DegInRad+(M_PI/2))}};
        }

    }else{
        cout<<"Drawing triangle point to origin "<<i<<endl;
        vertices[i] = {{1.00,1.00,1.00}, {0.0, 0.0}};
    }
}

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);

glBindVertexArray(VAO);

// Generate and bind (turn on) a buffer (storage location).
glGenBuffers(1, &Buffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffer);

// Transfer the vertex information to the buffer.
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, numVertices * sizeof(VertexData), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// Setup color data position information. Pointer to data on graphics card itself specifically the color.
//((position tag, number of colors, data-type identifier, to normalize or not, stride the number of bytes to the next color, where to start))
glVertexAttribPointer(vColor, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE, sizeof(VertexData), BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

// Setup vertex data position information. Never Normalize the position
//vPosition is 0, number of data-types, data-type, to normalize, stride, start (number of bytes to) of the first position data
glVertexAttribPointer(vPos, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexData),BUFFER_OFFSET(sizeof(vertices[0].rgb)));

// Set position indexes for shader streams. Turn on vPosition and vColor.
glEnableVertexAttribArray(vPos);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(vColor);
```

Comment: I do not see any question. So what is the problem?

Comment: @klaus, I think the second image is a much more interesting image than a 9-pointed. Keep it :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
numVertices = 6 * (rand() % 15 + 5);
```

You divide that in integer by three, so number of "points"  may not match?

why you generate number of vertices? Shouldn't you generate number of star points and calculate vertices from there?. Number of *unique* vertices for star `2*(star_points + 1)`.

Why it so? Outline of star contains `2*(star_points) + 1`, three per each lobe,  two of each shared between lobes. And you have center point.

OpenGL  allows several approaches:

1. push every triangle separately into vertex buffer, you'll use more data if a lot of vertices are shared: in your case  you'll have `6*star_points` vertices;
2. generate every vertex once, then use index buffer to create triangles or quads from them;
3. create a triangle strip or fan (fan is good choice here, you have the center).

You have wrong angle step, e.g. for  3-point star triangles are drawn in wrong order:

```
Drawing triangle point to origin 0
Drawing triangle point 1 at -0.866025,0.5
Drawing triangle point 2 at -2.59808,-1.5
Drawing triangle point to origin 3
Drawing triangle point 4 at 2.59808,-1.5
Drawing triangle point 5 at 0.866025,0.5
Drawing triangle point to origin 6
Drawing triangle point 7 at -0.866025,0.5
Drawing triangle point 8 at -2.59808,-1.5
Drawing triangle point to origin 9
Drawing triangle point 10 at 2.59808,-1.5
Drawing triangle point 11 at 0.866025,0.5
Drawing triangle point to origin 12
Drawing triangle point 13 at -0.866025,0.5
Drawing triangle point 14 at -2.59807,-1.5
Drawing triangle point to origin 15
Drawing triangle point 16 at 2.59808,-1.5
Drawing triangle point 17 at 0.866025,0.500001
```

This doesn't look right

```
DegToRad = 2 *M_PI / numPoints;
```

perhaps

```
DegToRad = M_PI / numPoints;
```

because each triangle is half of a lobe. The loop itself is wrong too by design. it leaves gaps between consecutive triangles, it increments angle during "drawing to origin" step. but next it would circle around the 360 degrees and begin fill those gaps..or not, if you have number of ends as a multiple of 3.

Comment: to clarify the numPoints is the number triangles that will be drawn and the number of points to the star would be that number divided by two sorry for confusion.

Comment: 2*PI / numPoints spaces out the triangles around the the circle equally having PI would try to space it around half like you said making a monstrosity.

Comment: @Klaus because the loop itself is wrong too by design. it leaves gaps between consecutive triangles, it increments angle during "drawing to origin" step.  but _next_ it would circle around the 360 degrees and begin fill those gaps..or not, if you have number of ends as a multiple of 3. In that case triangles would be repeated twice. I had shown that as example output

Answer (score 0):

In general your code works. There are only some small issues. I recommend to make the code easier to "read" and  a bit more comprehensible.

Take a random number:

```
int rnd = rand();
```

Calculate the number of peaks in the range from 5 to 20:

```
int peaks= (rand % 16 + 5);
```

Calcualte the number of vertices (6 per peak):

```
int numVertices = 6 * peaks;
```

Calculate the segment angle for 1 peak:

```
const float M_PI = 3.1415926535897;
float angPeakSeg = 2 * M_PI / (float)peaks;
```

Setup the vertices (your code will proper work):

```
float DegToRad = angPeakSeg/2.0f;
float r = 0.95;

std::vector<VertexData> vertices( numVertices );
for(int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++)
{
    float DegInRad = i * DegToRad;
    if(i % 3 !=0 )
    {
        if(i % 2 == 0)
            vertices[i] = {{1.00,0.00,0.00}, {r*cos(DegInRad+(M_PI/2)), r*sin(DegInRad+(M_PI/2))}};
        else
            vertices[i] = {{1.00,1.00,1.00}, {r/3*cos(DegInRad+(M_PI/2)), r/3*sin(DegInRad+(M_PI/2))}};
    }else{
        vertices[i] = {{1.00,1.00,1.00}, {0.0, 0.0}};
    }
}
```

Preview:

[image]